# Docker port not exposed on windows 11

Tags: windows, docker

Sadly i have to use Windows on my system, so i cannot change it to ubuntu.
I have installed docker for my angular test environments.
I am on windows 11, with WSL2, i had it working before but i'm strongly thinking something in the network start is keeping me from accessing it but what ?

- Windows firewall is disabled.
- On a seccond linux console within the host i can curl to my site and see web server responds
- opening port 127.0.0.1:4400/Login   (the normal opening path) doesnt allow me.
- From windows Telnet putty 127.0.0.1 to port 4400   i get nothing
- firefox error to site from windows "The connection was reset"
- chrome error to the site from windows "127.0.0.1 unexpectedly closed the connection."
- windows antivirus cannot disable it Sentinel One (it is not integrated in our browsers).
- Docker start `docker run -ti -p 4400:4400 <myimagename> /bin/bash`
- in Linux containter started ng `ng serve --port 4400 --disable-hostcheck`
- i have doubts about my routing table on windows 11, but i dont know how it should be for docker, and perhaps its OK ?
  route print (on windows no entries towards docker Gateway ??? )

  ```
   ===========================================================================
   Interface List
   8...c8 d9 d2 2d 7f 69 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM
   1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
   26...00 15 5d 26 4b dd ......Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
   ===========================================================================

   IPv4 Route Table
   ===========================================================================
   Active Routes:
   Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
           0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.25.0.50      10.25.1.109     25
           10.25.0.0    255.255.254.0         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
       10.25.1.109  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
       10.25.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
           127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
           127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
   127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.25.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
       172.25.48.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
       172.25.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
           224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
           224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
           224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
   255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
   ===========================================================================
  ```
- From windows ports are available ??

  ```
       C:\web>netstat -aon | findstr :4400
       TCP    0.0.0.0:4400           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16192
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53209        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53210        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53211        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53212        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53213        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53214        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53215        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53216        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53217        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53218        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    127.0.0.1:4400         127.0.0.1:53219        TIME_WAIT       0
       TCP    [::]:4400              [::]:0                 LISTENING       16192
       TCP    [::1]:4400             [::]:0                 LISTENING       17248
  ```
- docker config:
  docker inspect elated_babbage

  ```
   [
       {
           "Id": "c008e8a1ea57b598ccc8118f05e9c1604855e120ab880528981eab3cb5dc274f",
           "Created": "2023-08-08T13:28:16.1821888Z",
           "Path": "/bin/bash",
           "Args": [],
           "State": {
               "Status": "running",
               "Running": true,
               "Paused": false,
               "Restarting": false,
               "OOMKilled": false,
               "Dead": false,
               "Pid": 2554,
               "ExitCode": 0,
               "Error": "",
               "StartedAt": "2023-08-24T06:24:36.903499Z",
               "FinishedAt": "2023-08-24T06:24:32.3210839Z"
           },
           "Image": "sha256:074ef342bd522377a0e0c2f8f5c86f82d147d35019b3af75f15732a372944e87",
           "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c008e8a1ea57b598ccc8118f05e9c1604855e120ab880528981eab3cb5dc274f/resolv.conf",
           "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c008e8a1ea57b598ccc8118f05e9c1604855e120ab880528981eab3cb5dc274f/hostname",
           "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c008e8a1ea57b598ccc8118f05e9c1604855e120ab880528981eab3cb5dc274f/hosts",
           "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c008e8a1ea57b598ccc8118f05e9c1604855e120ab880528981eab3cb5dc274f/c008e8a1ea57b598ccc8118f05e9c1604855e120ab880528981eab3cb5dc274f-json.log",
           "Name": "/elated_babbage",
           "RestartCount": 0,
           "Driver": "overlay2",
           "Platform": "linux",
           "MountLabel": "",
           "ProcessLabel": "",
           "AppArmorProfile": "",
           "ExecIDs": [
               "2d83c745233e9cf15463f0d44ac20636e9aeebee6f7ca1df0e38721bf542c73c",
               "b6c4ceb4b114676f66bf32131bf91b50a6e3a0185457af5946f5a12d70dab0bb"
           ],
           "HostConfig": {
               "Binds": null,
               "ContainerIDFile": "",
               "LogConfig": {
                   "Type": "json-file",
                   "Config": {}
               },
               "NetworkMode": "default",
               "PortBindings": {
                   "4400/tcp": [
                       {
                           "HostIp": "",
                           "HostPort": "4400"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               "RestartPolicy": {
                   "Name": "no",
                   "MaximumRetryCount": 0
               },
               "AutoRemove": false,
               "VolumeDriver": "",
               "VolumesFrom": null,
               "ConsoleSize": [
                   42,
                   108
               ],
               "CapAdd": null,
               "CapDrop": null,
               "CgroupnsMode": "host",
               "Dns": [],
               "DnsOptions": [],
               "DnsSearch": [],
               "ExtraHosts": null,
               "GroupAdd": null,
               "IpcMode": "private",
               "Cgroup": "",
               "Links": null,
               "OomScoreAdj": 0,
               "PidMode": "",
               "Privileged": false,
               "PublishAllPorts": false,
               "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
               "SecurityOpt": null,
               "UTSMode": "",
               "UsernsMode": "",
               "ShmSize": 67108864,
               "Runtime": "runc",
               "Isolation": "",
               "CpuShares": 0,
               "Memory": 0,
               "NanoCpus": 0,
               "CgroupParent": "",
               "BlkioWeight": 0,
               "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
               "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
               "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
               "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
               "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
               "CpuPeriod": 0,
               "CpuQuota": 0,
               "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
               "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
               "CpusetCpus": "",
               "CpusetMems": "",
               "Devices": [],
               "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
               "DeviceRequests": null,
               "MemoryReservation": 0,
               "MemorySwap": 0,
               "MemorySwappiness": null,
               "OomKillDisable": false,
               "PidsLimit": null,
               "Ulimits": null,
               "CpuCount": 0,
               "CpuPercent": 0,
               "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
               "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
               "MaskedPaths": [
                   "/proc/asound",
                   "/proc/acpi",
                   "/proc/kcore",
                   "/proc/keys",
                   "/proc/latency_stats",
                   "/proc/timer_list",
                   "/proc/timer_stats",
                   "/proc/sched_debug",
                   "/proc/scsi",
                   "/sys/firmware"
               ],
               "ReadonlyPaths": [
                   "/proc/bus",
                   "/proc/fs",
                   "/proc/irq",
                   "/proc/sys",
                   "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
               ]
           },
           "GraphDriver": {
               "Data": {
                   "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf4025975b12a8ec4c75dde7a4c858e545cf7f7a896777d46eded75a9582d022-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a51a74e187035ef6fa0146dbc6751bbd949d683e43ab0617a21a7c52c97ea883/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5d091946c590c1644c54cae8684dd2deb481c20156133f6cdbee4284158ef996/diff",
                   "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf4025975b12a8ec4c75dde7a4c858e545cf7f7a896777d46eded75a9582d022/merged",
                   "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf4025975b12a8ec4c75dde7a4c858e545cf7f7a896777d46eded75a9582d022/diff",
                   "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bf4025975b12a8ec4c75dde7a4c858e545cf7f7a896777d46eded75a9582d022/work"
               },
               "Name": "overlay2"
           },
           "Mounts": [],
           "Config": {
               "Hostname": "c008e8a1ea57",
               "Domainname": "",
               "User": "",
               "AttachStdin": true,
               "AttachStdout": true,
               "AttachStderr": true,
               "ExposedPorts": {
                   "4400/tcp": {}
               },
               "Tty": true,
               "OpenStdin": true,
               "StdinOnce": true,
               "Env": [
                   "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
               ],
               "Cmd": [
                   "/bin/bash"
               ],
               "Image": "batnetwebbase",
               "Volumes": null,
               "WorkingDir": "",
               "Entrypoint": null,
               "OnBuild": null,
               "Labels": {
                   "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
                   "org.opencontainers.image.version": "22.04"
               }
           },
           "NetworkSettings": {
               "Bridge": "",
               "SandboxID": "8953b243463252eddf22233ade80a47669e787378ade9e6a45aad6fffa8ee8f1",
               "HairpinMode": false,
               "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
               "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "Ports": {
                   "4400/tcp": [
                       {
                           "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                           "HostPort": "4400"
                       }
                   ]
               },
               "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/8953b2434632",
               "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
               "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
               "EndpointID": "189c1570eca54bcf01ea7309a93a7ec4a6e240b74a5775286fa81a84b456feeb",
               "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
               "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
               "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
               "IPPrefixLen": 16,
               "IPv6Gateway": "",
               "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
               "Networks": {
                   "bridge": {
                       "IPAMConfig": null,
                       "Links": null,
                       "Aliases": null,
                       "NetworkID": "00940e41662d06586b84b480eb93f1cabb6f4de2e34688b4c119cacc72215bf4",
                       "EndpointID": "189c1570eca54bcf01ea7309a93a7ec4a6e240b74a5775286fa81a84b456feeb",
                       "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                       "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                       "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                       "IPv6Gateway": "",
                       "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                       "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                       "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                       "DriverOpts": null
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ]
  ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the default route of the docker bridge network wasnt listed
I typed in Windows `route add 172.17.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 172.17.0.1`

After that i could visit my angular site, which is kinda weird.
So i'm posting it as an answer as it works.
Though i am not sure why adding that 172 route allows me access to http://127.0.0.1:4400/login
Which is on 127.0.0.1

Maybe docker is unable to alter the routing tables when it starts up not sure i think its a bug. I cannot clearly explain why this works (routing commands are a bit of a mystery to me) , not sure if I should post it as an answer therefore, on the other hand i hope it helps others

after it my routing table looked like

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.25.0.50      10.25.1.109     25
        10.25.0.0    255.255.254.0         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
      10.25.1.109  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
      10.25.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.17.0.0      255.255.0.0       172.17.0.1      10.25.1.109     26
      172.25.48.0    255.255.240.0         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
      172.25.48.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
    172.25.63.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.25.1.109    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.25.48.1   5256
```

Comment: it seams to work temporally , and by now it has stopped working i dont understand\

Comment: It turned out this is the solution though, docker sometimes needs a restart of the whole OS...